# Print a list of dictionaries to a file

Tags: python, json, python-3.6

Python 3.6

I have a program that is generating a list of dictionaries.

If I print it to the screen with:

```
print(json.dumps(output_lines, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

It prints out exactly as I want to see it:

```
[
    {
        "runts": 0,     
        "giants": 0,     
        "throttles": 0,
        "input errors": 0,
        "CRC": 0,
        "frame": 0,
        "overrun": 0,
        "ignored": 0,
        "watchdog": 0,
        "pause input": 0,
        "input packets with dribble condition detected": 0,
        "underruns": 0,
        "output errors": 0,
        "collisions": 0,
        "interface resets": 2,
        "babbles": 0,
        "late collision": 0,
        "deferred": 0,
        "lost carrier": 0,
        "no carrier": 0,
        "PAUSE output": 0,
        "output buffer failures": 0,
        "output buffers swapped out": 0
    },
    {
        "runts": 0,
        "giants": 0,
        "throttles": 0,
        "input errors": 0,
        "CRC": 0,
        "frame": 0,
        "overrun": 0,
        "ignored": 0,
        "watchdog": 0,
        "pause input": 0,
        "input packets with dribble condition detected": 0,
        "underruns": 0,
        "output errors": 0,
        "collisions": 0,
        "interface resets": 2,
        "babbles": 0,
        "late collision": 0,
        "deferred": 0,
        "lost carrier": 0,
        "no carrier": 0,
        "PAUSE output": 0,
        "output buffer failures": 0,
        "output buffers swapped out": 0
    },
```

But if I try to print it to a file with:

```
outputfile = ("d:\\mark\\python\\Projects\\error_detect\\" + hostname)
# print(json.dumps(output_lines, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
output_lines.append(json.dumps(output_lines, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
del output_lines[-1]
with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(output_lines, f)
```

The file is one giant line of text.

I want the formatting in the file to look like it does when I print to the screen.

I do not understand why I am losing the formatting.

Comment: You need to either `dump` the data structure directly or `write` the string created by `dumps`. I suggest the former.

Comment: Um, you append it to `output_lines` and then right away remove it? What's that supposed to achieve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Say your program generates this list of dictionaries

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(list(range(2)),list(range(2)))), dict(zip(list(range(2)),list(range(2))))]
>>> list_of_dicts
[{0: 0, 1: 1}, {0: 0, 1: 1}]
```

What you can do is

```
>>> import json
>>> str_object = json.dumps(list_of_dicts, indent=4)
>>> repr(str_object)
'[\n    {\n        "0": 0, \n        "1": 1\n    }, \n    {\n        "0": 0, \n        "1": 1\n    }\n]'
>>> str_object
[
    {
        "0": 0, 
        "1": 1
    }, 
    {
        "0": 0, 
        "1": 1
    }
]
```

Now you can write `str_object`

```
>>> with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(str_object)
```

Which makes the formatting in the file be as it is when you print it to the screen.

Comment: I am curious of this -1. I would be glad to know why since **this works and adresses the question**.

Comment: Tnerual, 1) I did not do the -1, in fact I did the opposite because your answer is spot on perfect.  I just tried it and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I did, but my score is still so low that I get a message telling me that my vote was registered but will not count towards public display.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is `json.dump` with `indent` and it should be fine:

```
outputfile = ("d:\\mark\\python\\Projects\\error_detect\\" + hostname)
# print(json.dumps(output_lines, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
# output_lines.append(json.dumps(output_lines, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
# del output_lines[-1]
with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(output_lines, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

It doesn’t make much sense to me to format to a string and then re run dump on the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply outputting the formatted `json.dumps`, rather than running it through `json.dump` again.

```
with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(output_lines)
```

Comment: `output_lines` is a list of dictionaries. This should raise an an error because `write` needs a string.